# heroku deployment failed to push some refs?

Tags: git, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

trying to deploy my first app to heroku, following this guide: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#deploying-code. I executed  ssh-keygen -t rsa.
When i try to execute :

```
git push heroku master
```

I get this error:
[image]

Comment: Please refer to my answer below for resolving this issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/33007405/4902373

Answer (score 0):

The "no Cedar-supported app" implies that what you pushed doesn't contain any code or files that lets Heroku recognise what kind of application you are pushing.

What is in the git repo that you're pushing?

For example, for a Ruby app,  [you need a Gemfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#general-support-activation).  The [other languages](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/language-support) have similar requirements.